# How to determine which program is making a certain sound in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I'm experiencing an annoying "female robotic" sound effect saying "loading complete" at uncertain interval in windows 7.

I want to shut down that noise for good. To do that, I have to determine which program is making this sound. I tried to open the "sound mixer" window, only to find to program last made any sound, one is official GTalk client, one is system sound. I tried to close GTalk and the sound still existed.

I started experiencing this issue not long after I installed a "driver" program for Rapoo E9198 wireless keyboard.

Comment: just in case anyone is wondering in general how to figure out what application is causing a sound - [this is pure genius](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-application-making-sounds-in-background/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those sounds come from your Google Chrome/Firefox extension called "Magic Actions for YouTube™. When any YouTube video is completely loaded these sounds are played. You can disable this feature in extension's options.

Comment: Thank you man, finally figured out! This is so annoying!

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong place to ask but do you by any chance know where the option to turn off this sound is located? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Nevermind, I deleted the .ogg file in the extension directory for Magic Actions and it doesn't play anymore. :)

Answer (score 7):

Your Windows 7 **Volume Mixer** shows sound level for each application.

Click speaker icon in tray, then click `Mixer` underneath your sound device to show applications that use that device.

Look at the sample screen. The green bar points Foobar as the source of sound:

[image]:

**Edit 1:**

If you cannot find your app here, it may mean the process is outside the scope of your current user priviledges. You may try following:

- Temporarily [disable User Account Control](http://windows.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows-vista/turn-user-account-control-on-or-off) or login as `BUILT-IN\Administrator`
- <del>Alternatively, you may try to login as `SYSTEM` user, though I never attempted such a feat on a full desktop scale.</del> Launch mixer as `SYSTEM` user use [psExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) tool: `psExec -i -s sndvol.exe`

**Edit 2:**

Google suggests: "[HyperSound](http://www.hyperspin-fe.com/forum/showthread.php?26122-quot-Loading-Complete-quot-Sample)"

Comment: thank you, but @RAJ had the right answer

Answer (score 3):

You can mute individual program's channels in the Windows 7 mixer. Mute them one at a time for an extended period of time and you'll be able to narrow down what is causing the noise.

If it's System Sounds it's probably a something you can change inside the Sounds section of the Control Panel.