# How to list all applications currently playing audio?

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio

Sometimes I have several applications open that are playing audio. Is there any way to list all of the applications that are using audio ports within windows?

Comment: Why not just look at the mixer? It should have an entry for all programs using the sound system, and any that are active should show the volume meter bar bouncing with audio activity. See this answer: http://superuser.com/a/652027/23133 Does that suffice?

Comment: Yes, I think this does solve the problem I asked. Really though, I have some radio station playing on my computer when I have my headphones plugged in. I can't hear it when I unplug my headphones, and no audio is shown to be playing on that audio mixer. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd advise starting a new question, only make it about your actual problem as you've described in your comment (including what you've tried already).